# How to prevent an object with a null value from being pushed into a stack?

Tags: java, javafx, integer, nullreferenceexception

Just as the title suggests, I'm trying to create a card game here but am currently having trouble with a discard function in which, I select a card from my hand and discard it into a stack. Each card has a value from 0 to 12. But the problem is that at times I get a `NullPointerException` from getting a card with a `null` value (which should not exist). I've traced the code and determined that somehow. On top of discarding a normal card, a card with a `null` value is discarded as well, given that after testing some code to print the card values of each card in the stack (from top to bottom), the exception appears *after* the card I've discarded is printed.

Here's the action listener or a button that I click in order to discard a card:

```
pDiscard1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            if (cardSelected && (dPile == null && sPile == null)) {
                                game.pdc[0].discard(card);
                                for (int i = 0; i < game.playerHand.size(); i++) {
                                    if (game.playerHand.get(i) == card) {
                                        game.playerHand.remove(i);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                cardSelected = false;
                                discarded = true;
                                display();
                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                            System.out.println("The card you have attempted to discard is invalid. You can only discard cards from your hand.");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

And down here is the code for the discard:

```
void discard(SkipBoCard card) {
        dPile.push(card);
    }
```

If any other information is needed, please do let me know. Any help regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SkipBo.SkipBoGUI.display(SkipBoGUI.java:618)
    at SkipBo.SkipBoGUI.<init>(SkipBoGUI.java:507)
    at SkipBo.SkipBoMain.main(SkipBoMain.java:5)
```

Line 507 is the call for the display method (which updates the visuals of the GUI), and 618 is a part of an if-statement that changes the text of the cards in the buttons/panels for a card. This is because it doesn't have a try-catch exception handler because I'm try to get to the bottom of why this problem is happening (thus far no luck). This information certainly feels like a dead end, but I hope this can help in any way.

Comment: Share the error stack trace. On catch block add e.printStackTrace(); and we can handle NPE

Comment: You don't show where the value of `card` is set, so it's impossible to say why it's null.